# How to get access to the 2-legged OAuth 2.0 for LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I have a company LinkedIn page for which I would like to automate fetching reactions/engagement/etc. of the posts for use in a marketing dashboard. Since I want it to be automatic, I would require 2-legged OAuth on LinkedIn.

Unfortunately, when trying to generate a token it does not allow me to do so:
[image: 2-legged option not clickable]

Unfortunately, I did not find any information on how to get access to 2-legged OAuth on any of the Microsoft's documentation for the API. I get the 401 error.

These are the products I have enabled:
[image: Selected Products]

And here are the scopes:
[image: Scopes]

Any information on how to get access to the 2-legged OAuth is appreciated.